# Notification doesn't go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, notifications

I have a notification of a reply to a comment of mine which doesn't disappear from the notification icon on the top of the page. I click on it and it clears but, when I refresh the page or go to another page, there it is again. It happened right after the scheduled maintenance today.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjMffHG1V_Q

Comment: Thanks for the laugh, Gerry. But now I have two notifications that don't go away.

Comment: If misery truly loves company, you may be interested to know there's a similar complaint at m.se, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16599/groundhog-day-bug (so perhaps it's system-wide).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: also the notifications of votes are broken: they don't go away and are not updated (mine still lists +10 from yesterday, not the +20 from today)

Comment: Is the problem gone for you guys now? It's gone for me.

Comment: It also seems to be gone for me.

Comment: Yes, it's gone now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an artifact of some fail-over testing we did during the weekend. Sorry about the noise, this should be cleared up for everyone by now.

For those that don't know, we have redundant data centers, data replicates between them. If something happens in the US East, we can (very quickly) come back up in Oregon, without anyone losing anything they've  recently written.

The process of doing that is remarkably smooth given what's involved, but there are some rough spots we're trying to smooth out.

Comment: The problem was indeed gone a few days ago, but it's back now.

Comment: And it's gone again --- maybe it just came by for a brief visit.